# install a door on stairs

Tags: doors, door-frame

I'd like to install a door at the stairs in the basement:

I will most likely buy a pre-hung door that comes with a door frame.  The wall construction is drywall, the left and right edges have 2"x4" boards behind.

What would be my steps to install the door with its frame within the stairway.

[image]

Comment: You should do a little research, google "how to hang a prehung door".  There are many different ways. Get familiar with them, decide on which one fits your situation and then ask some specific questions. The way it it now, it would be opinion based.

Comment: You may consider a sliding barn door. I just built and installed one on the bottom of some stairs for a makeshift mother in-law space, mostly to keep the cat downstairs.  I had to use a ceiling mount track because one side had a perpendicular wall so there was nowhere to mount a wall track.

Comment: @AlaskaMan, thanks for comment. Your idea about sliding door is interesting. In my case the basement's hallway isn't too wide, so slide door would save up space. Did you build/design the door yourself or bought some kind of kit (rails, and door etc.)?

Answer (score 5):

The Code requires a landing at the top and bottom of all stairways, except a landing is not required at the top of a stairway provided the door does not swing out over the stairs. (See ICC R311.5.4)

If you need to install a door at the bottom of the stairs, maybe you could turn the door 90 degrees and install it in the hallway.

If you try to install it at the bottom of the stairs, the doorknob will be difficult to reach when you descend the stairs.